# JSON Object return undefined?

Tags: javascript, json

This array.

```
var theObject = [{"id":"412","thn_akademik":"20152","id_prodi":"15301","kode_mk":"20038","tanggal":"23\/8\/2016","jam_1":"17:00\t","jam_2":"19:00\t","npm":"07150100190","flag1":"0","flag2":"0"},{"id":"558","thn_akademik":"20152","id_prodi":"15301","kode_mk":"20053","tanggal":"25\/8\/2016","jam_1":"17:00\t","jam_2":"19:00\t","npm":"07150100190","flag1":"0","flag2":"0"},{"id":"704","thn_akademik":"20152","id_prodi":"15301","kode_mk":"20052","tanggal":"30\/8\/2016","jam_1":"17:00\t","jam_2":"19:00\t","npm":"07150100190","flag1":"0","flag2":"0"},{"id":"850","thn_akademik":"20152","id_prodi":"15301","kode_mk":"000047","tanggal":"31\/8\/2016","jam_1":"17:00\t","jam_2":"19:00\t","npm":"07150100190","flag1":"0","flag2":"0"},{"id":"996","thn_akademik":"20152","id_prodi":"15301","kode_mk":"20050","tanggal":"23\/8\/2016","jam_1":"09:00\t","jam_2":"11:00\t","npm":"07150100190","flag1":"0","flag2":"0"},{"id":"1142","thn_akademik":"20152","id_prodi":"15301","kode_mk":"20051","tanggal":"25\/8\/2016","jam_1":"09:00\t","jam_2":"11:00\t","npm":"07150100190","flag1":"0","flag2":"0"},{"id":"1288","thn_akademik":"20152","id_prodi":"15301","kode_mk":"000030","tanggal":"30\/8\/2016","jam_1":"09:00\t","jam_2":"11:00\t","npm":"07150100190","flag1":"0","flag2":"0"}] ;


for (var i = 0; i < theObject.length; i++) { 
    alert(theObject[i].kode_mk);
}
```

It works when i test in on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XX2sB/59/).

But when i try in on my apps in return undefined.

anyone know what make this happen?

Comment: return? there is no return in the code - there is no function to have a return either

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: keep up the good fight @FelixKling - unfortunately, the next step is "I have a JSON"

Comment: nevermind, i have to use JSON.Parse in my apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a ***javascript*** object ***NOT*** a ***JSON*** object. It's not clear what you're asking "***But when i try in on my apps in return undefined.***". What app?

If your app is retrieving JSON, you must ***parse*** it before trying to loop through it. E.g

```
var json = JSON.parse(JSON_HERE);
```

You can then loop through that json object and retrieve the `kode_mk`.

If you have code from your "app", please provide it. Tell us what your app is doing and how it's getting the JSON

Comment: Thank you . . . .~

Comment: sorry i  always call my project as an app.

Comment: why in fiddle i don't need to parse but in my code i need to parse it?

Comment: Your fiddle is using a javascript object. JSON is a string representation of a js object. It may help for you to read up on how json works and what it actually is ~> http://www.json.org/ @NamikazeSheena

Comment: in fiddle you have a javascript object hard coded ... who knows what you do in your "real" code, because you didn't share that - it's probably a JSON **STRING** which must be *parsed*

Comment: I don't know...there is such a thing as JSON object with methods such as, parse and stringify but I understand what you are saying in the context of the question.